# How to get odds ratio using glmnet?

Tags: lasso, odds-ratio, glmnet

I ran three regularization methods, lasso, ridge, and elastic net. Lasso was able to get the best accuracy, so I'm selecting it. Is there a way to calculate odds ratio from the coefficients? Does it make sense to do it in glmnet?

I took the following steps:

```
train.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                             number = 10, 
                             repeats = 5, 
                             allowParallel = T,
                             verboseIter = T)

set.seed(1234)
lasso_model <- train(traget~ ., 
                trainTransformed[,-2], 
                trControl = train.control, 
                method = "glmnet",
                tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 1, 
                                       lambda = seq(0.0001, 0.05, length = 5)),
                family = "binomial")
```

#### Plot and predict the model

```
plot(lasso_model$finalModel, xvar = "lambda", label = T)

plot(lasso_model$finalModel, xvar = "dev", label = T)

plot(varImp(lasso_model, scale = F))


p.lasso.pred <- predict(lasso_model, testTransformed)

p.lasso.pred.cm <- confusionMatrix(p.lasso.pred, testTransformed$BMK_R_Derailment, mode = "prec_recall")
```

Now, all tutorials that I've read stops at this point. I'm really confused as to whether to stop here, or take the features from lasso with coefficients > 0 and run logistic again to get the odds ratio for the coefficients.

And I also did that. However, most of the variables are not significant (which is fine). Then should I select the variables that are significant and do the regular (step-wise - not sure if I should do this) logistic regression? or leave the model as is because lasso produced those features?

Answer (score 1):

If you ran glmnet with `family="binomial"` , the coefficients are log odds ratio, so exponential of these will give the odds ratio. You can check out their [website](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html#log) where it writes (sorry I took a screen shot because of some symbols):

[image]

So for example:

```
library(MASS)
library(glmnet)

fit = cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(Pima.tr[,-ncol(Pima.tr)]),
y= Pima.tr$type,family="binomial",alpha=1)
```

Most likely you can follow the recommendation of 1se from best for the best lambda:

```
opt.lam = fit$lambda.1se
as.matrix(coef(fit, s = opt.lam))
                      1
(Intercept) -5.49752003
npreg        0.02408488
glu          0.02132413
bp           0.00000000
skin         0.00000000
bmi          0.03009826
ped          0.50900237
age          0.02462429
```

In this dataset, the coefficients indicate how much 1 unit of the predictors increase the log-odds of having type "yes" (or diabetes). You convert the above to log-odds by take the exponential.

Comment: @StupidWold, I'm really confused now. SO answer in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/428349/get-odds-ratios-with-confidence-intervals-from-a-lasso-regression-model stats that lasso coefficients should not be used for inference. So, does this mean we have to extract vars from lasso and run `glm` again?

Comment: Ok, if you read that post, the OP wrote "I do not know how to get odds ratios with respective 95% CIs for the covariates retained" . So, if you need a 95% CI, you should not use the lasso coefficients. This is the inference part i guess

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to do? Because your question just says, "get odds ratio", and this is possible by just converting the coefficients to odds ratio

Comment: So, this means I can use the odds ratio as you showed above in my results? And, state that the odds of getting diabetes increases by a factor of `exp(0.024) = 1.02` for 1 unit increase in npreg?

Comment: Sorry if this is long winded. I don't want to tell you the wrong thing. Are you doing inference ? That is, are you trying to say something about the effects of your variable? For example in the above, if you are trying to say for example npreg has an effect, and it's increases the odds by ... , then most likely you should run the glm using the non-zero coefficients from lasso

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too. That's why I was asking. I've updated my question to show what I've done

Comment: Then in this situation, you are using lasso as some kind of a feature selection, and then inferring its effect from glm. There are some problems with this, especially when it comes to correlated variables, but yeah maybe you can elaborate more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106470/discussion-between-user1828605-and-stupidwolf).